# how can i get onchange parameter?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi i want to get  "datos"

```
$('#proveedor_albaran').on('change',function (e) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var datos = {
        url:"/admin/compras/ajax/getAlbaranesFacturas",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id :id, _token:  window.Laravel.csrfToken}
    };
});
```

And for Datatable, this is out from function on change. I want this because the last function on click a row makes multiples console.log.

```
 var tabla_albaranes_facturas = $('#tabla_albaranes_facturas').DataTable({
     "language": {
         url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json'
     },
     ajax: datos,
     columns: [
     });
     tabla_albaranes_facturas.on('click', '.abreEnlace', function () {
         console.log("hola");
         if ($('#facturar').is(':checked')) {
             console.log("adios");
         }
     });
```

how can i pass and get parameter from function on Change?

Comment: Are you trying to get datos using an AJAX request which POST data?

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez Hi, i'm trying to get datos out of function " on.("change")

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to extract "datos" to a function. Following this idea you can call to this where needed.

```js
var datos;

function getDatos() {
  return {
        url:"/admin/compras/ajax/getAlbaranesFacturas",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id :id, _token:  window.Laravel.csrfToken}
  };
)

$('#proveedor_albaran').on('change',function (e) {
  var id = $(this).val();
  datos = getDatos(); 
});

var tabla_albaranes_facturas = $('#tabla_albaranes_facturas').DataTable({
   "language": {
       url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json'
   },
   ajax: getDatos,
   columns: [
   });
   tabla_albaranes_facturas.on('click', '.abreEnlace', function () {
     console.log("hola");
     if ($('#facturar').is(':checked')) {
         console.log("adios");
     }
 });
```